# Can a JSF/Primefaces disabled button be enabled by using the browser (changing css or js)?

Tags: javascript, css, jsf, primefaces

If a JSF/Primefaces button is disabled using:

```
<p:commandButton disabled="#{bean.disable}" value="My Button" />
```

Can an user enable it by changing css or javascript in the browser (May be using firebug)? I ask because when I restrict clicks on a button, I don't want the users to do tricks in the browser and enable it back.

Comment: One of the great advantages of JSF is the 'automatic' server side counterpart of the security features

Comment: Thanks BalusC for clarifying it is duplicated and thanks Kukeltje for your comment.